# NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsInstanceOfType() is obsolete

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm currently reading the book [Professional Enterprise .NET](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Enterprise-NET.productCd-0470447613.html) and I've noticed this warning in some of the example programs:

```
'NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsInstanceOfType(System.Type, object)' is obsolete
```

Now I may have already answered my own question but, to fix this warning is it simply a case of replacing Assert.IsInstanceOfType() with Assert.IsInstanceOf()? For example this:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(ClassName), variableName);
```

would become:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(ClassName), variableName);
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

From [the NUnit documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=typeAsserts&r=2.5.1) the `IsInstanceOf` method is a generic method so you would use this:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOf<ClassName>(variableName);
```

Answer (score 21):

For completeness: if you use [the constraint model](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.5.4):

```
Assert.That(variableName, Is.InstanceOf<ClassName>());
```

or your test class inherits `AssertionHelper`:

```
Expect(variableName, InstanceOf<ClassName>());
```